# Using storage for android Quiz app made in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

I would like to learn, how to store number of correctly answered questions in my app. I also want to store another data but only of numeric type. I would like to ask which database to use for this purpose and how, because i have no clue.

I expect to store the data and then use it inuser statistics

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to store data and use it later in `Android`. Steps:

1. First you need to initialize `SharedPreferences`:

```
val sp = getSharedPreferences("SharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE)
val spEdit = sp.edit()
```

2. Then, to save data, you have to use:

```
spEdit.putString("YOUR_KEY", YOUR_DATA)
spEdit.apply()
```

3. To retrieve the data, you have to use:

```
val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("SharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE)
val savedData = sharedPref.getString("YOUR_KEY", "")
```

You have to replace `YOUR_KEY` with any string that represents the key to the saved data. `YOUR_DATA` has to be replaced with the data that you want to save. To save strings, you have to use `.putString()`, for integers, `.putInt()` and so on.